# Hover not working on navigation bar links

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm sure it's a simple fix. It's been a long time since I've made a website and am trying to make it so that when the user hovers over the links in the navigation bar to go green > This shade: #007D68, and when they are active to go orange > this shade: #F68E56. However somewhere along the line I've made an error.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="EvositeCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="NavBar">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

        <div id="VictoriaHouse">
            <img src="Images/VictoriaHouse.JPG" alt="Victoria House & Viney Court">
        </div>
        <ul>
       <li> <a href="Evosite.html" id="NavHome"> Home </span> </a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#" class="NavLink"> News </a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#" class="NavLink"> Tenants </a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#" class="NavLink"> Heritage </a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#" class="NavLink"> About Us </a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#" class="NavLink"> Book the Meeting Room </a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#" id="NavContact"> Contact Us </a> </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</nav> <!-- Ends NavBar <-->
</div> <!-- Ends wrapper -->
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#wrapper {
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#VictoriaHouse {
padding-left:200px;
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
padding-right:120px;
float:left;
}

/* NavBar formatting */

ul {
float:inline-block;
padding-top:45px;
}

li {
display: inline;
}

a { 
font-family: Bree Serif;
font-size:20px
}

 a:link {
color:black;
background-color:white;
}

a:hover {
color: #007D68; /* Green */
}

a:active {
text-decoration:none;
color: #F68E56; /*orange */
}

a:visited {
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:white;
}

.NavLink {
margin-left:20px;
text-decoration:none;
}

#NavHome {
margin-left:30px;
}

#NavContact {
margin-left:20px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I solved it by swapping the link to my CSS and the bootstrap CSS. Bootstrap had been overwriting mine as it came after. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3):

`font-color` is an invalid property, `color` is the one you're looking for. Try:

```
a:hover {
  color: #007D68; /* Green */
}
```

Comment: My mistake, I'd forgotten to change that back before posting. That doesn't work either. I'll change that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the pseudo-classes in a wrong order. From [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes):

> Note that the A:hover must be placed after the A:link and A:visited rules, since otherwise the cascading rules will hide the 'color' property of the A:hover rule. Similarly, because A:active is placed after A:hover, the active color (lime) will apply when the user both activates and hovers over the A element.

The correct order should be:

```
a:link    { color: red }    /* unvisited links */
a:visited { color: blue }   /* visited links   */
a:hover   { color: yellow } /* user hovers     */
a:active  { color: lime }   /* active links    */
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/41w2Ltje/)

Comment: I changed my CSS file to follow that order however it hasn't appeared to have made any difference on my site. Which is very confusing as your example works fine.

Comment: I don't know, maybe clearing your browser cache (`Ctrl + F5`)?

Answer (score 1):

There some misconceptions you need to be aware of.

First, you got the hover behavior working correctly. That was easy. Your misconception, and you are not alone. Many people share this with you, unless they are UI/UX engineers, then they would know :) is that :active represents the active page so they expect the link for the active page to be colored or styled as they expected. That is not right.

The .active pseudoclass is only represented when the link is active (as long as the event is running) to test it. set `a:active {color: red}` and then click and hold the link and you will see is red for as long as it is held. Meaning the event is not finished. When you release, it goes back to its natural state.

The right way to do this is to create an .active class and assign the respective styles you desire to that class. Then add the active class to that link whenever that page is current. You can do this via client side (JQuery or Javascript) or Server-side (PHP or ASP.NET) depending on your framework.

Another big tip I can give you. Avoid using IDs for styling. Use classes instead. IDs do not cascade and they are unique (only one per page) that makes it hard to style a website and specially to use globally. Reserve the use of IDs for server side functionality only.

I would post examples, but I think the information I just gave you lead you through the right path quite fine, specially since this is not your first rodeo :)

[image]

[image]

tested

[corrected - follow link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpRBvM)

Good luck!

Comment: I tried your example of setting a:active to color:red however when I tested it by holding it down it didn't change. It's still the default blue with an underline, despite the colour having been changed and the text-decoration set to none.

Comment: I didn't test it either.  It's a normal behavior unless it's being overwritten at the DOM or by an !important property.  But your focus should be on creating the .active or .current class

Comment: I tested and posted a screenshot of the put to show you

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think you were right with something overwriting it at the DOM. I used !important to counteract it, as nothing else seemed to work.

Comment: Not a problem. I see this all the time. I corrected your code pen and added an active class for you to see it in action. What you need now is to add the class dynamically server side or using JS

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was adding !important; to the elements that weren't working e.g.

```
a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color: #007D68; /* Green */
}
```

This doesn't work, when you hover over it, it's just the default blue underline.
However when adding !important after the none, after text-decoration, it works.

My guess is that an element in the bootstrap navigation bar I am using was overwriting it.

If anyone has a more efficient solution then that would be welcome, however for now that solves my problem.

Comment: Oh dear, I am very silly... the solution was that I had my CSS followed by the bootstrap CSS, so it just overwrote mine. Swapping them around so that bootstrap was first then my CSS solved it.